# How to import/sync comments from Disqus into my drupal database?

Tags: 7, comments

After reading [the module´s homepage](http://drupal.org/project/disqus), I understand that there´s an easy way to get disquss comments easily imported/exported from your Drupal database in D7.

> To import/sync: You can do a one-time import at Comments->Disqus
>   Import. Specify the timestamp you want to import from. You can have
>   comments automatically import from Disqus on an interval basis. Turn
>   this on in the import settings at Site Config -> Disqus -> Import.
>   Turning on syncing will query Disqus for any comments that came in
>   since the last import.

But how do I actually do that?

I don´t have any "Disquss import" tab or link under "admin/content/comment"

And under "/admin/config/services/disqus" I don´t have any "Import" link or tab.
Maybe I´m missing something?

Thanks for your help!!
Rosamunda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading under the heading "Disqus Migrate Sub-module" on the module page, the import functionality/disqus migrate module seems to only be for the drupal 6 version.

Answer (score 1):

here is some [sandbox project](https://drupal.org/sandbox/sanchiz/1999128) for drupal 7, that import comments from disqus to drupal core comments